# Взаимодействие с рабочими процессами

Tags: стилистика

Правильно ли говорить: "взаимодействие с рабочими процессами"?

Comment: Приведите предложение полностью, также можно добавить контекст.

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий процесс замкнут, в нём можно *участвовать*, ему можно *содействовать* (поддерживать).

Взаимодействие предполагает и относительную свободу в принятии решений, и неопределённось временной дистанции, что в рамках рабочего процесса **недопустимо**. В него включаются и его налаживают (вносят стабильность) на старте запуска. На то он и рабочий.